# How can I get a specific div from an outside iframe when I am already within a different iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have issues related to the following code

This is my main Page:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="pagewrapper"> 
        <div class="page">
                <iframe id="TabContentIframe" 
                    src="/MyTestWebsite4/TabContent/Details/8">
                </iframe>
                <iframe id="TabContentIframe" 
                    src="/MyTestWebsite4/TabContent/Details/8">
                </iframe>
                <iframe id="TabContentIframe" 
                    src="/MyTestWebsite4/TabContent/Details/8">
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The TabContentIframe looks Like This:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="pagewrapper"> 
            <div class="DivIWant">
                <iframe id="MainContentIframe" 
                    src="/MyTestWebsite4/MainContent/Details/8">
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And The MainContentIframe Looks Like This:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="pagewrapper"> 
            <div iD = "BtnIPressed"></div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there are all in the same domain.

If I press the `BtnIPressed`, how can I get the `DivIWant` that is closest to the iframe within I pressed the button?

Comment: have you tried `top.window.document.getElementById("DivIWant")`?

Comment: I am sorry,
I thought to simplify my question, And I got all those right answer but not help full for my case. In My case the <code>divIwant</code> is inside the <code>TabContentIframe</code> and my main page has many of those, I want the one which in the iframe that is closest to the <code>btnIpressed</code>, all those answer won't help cause I just get all of the DIV's and not just the closest.

Comment: I Edited the question, sorry for all the mix up.

Comment: So you are including an infinite amount of iframes, look at the source of the inner one. :)

Comment: Which inner one, I don't know which one I got from. that is my mains issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orginal Answer was:

```
alert(parent.parent.getElementById("DivIWant").innerHTML)
```

But now you changed the location of the div so it would just be one level up.

```
alert(parent.getElementById("DivIWant").innerHTML)
```

Walking up parents until you find a matching div

```
var par = null;
var div = null;
while(par!==window){
    par = par.parent;
    var div = par.getElementById("DivIWant")
    if(div){       
         break;
    }
}
if(div){
    alert(div.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry,
I thought to simplify my question, And I got all those right answer but not help full for my case. In My case the <code>divIwant</code> is inside the <code>TabContentIframe</code> and my main page has many of those, I want the one which in the iframe that is closest to the <code>btnIpressed</code>, all those answer won't help cause I just get all of the DIV's and not just the closest. Any one know how to do that? thanks, and sorry for the mix up.

Comment: The parent property returns the parent window of the current window so ask for the parent I'll get MainContentIframe, the DivIWant is still outside that iframe, Ask for parent again and I'll get the Main document which include many TabContentIframe which I don't know which one I got out from...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.top.document.getElementById("DivIWant");
```

Comment: I Edited the question, sorry for all the mix up.